# unqualified-id before '[' token c++ error

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm doing  a c++ app and I'm having some troubles while doing it and I can't fix the error.
I have a class ratinmaze that I'd like to use in the main class, but i get a lot of errors..

ratinmaze.h

```
#ifndef RATINMAZE_H
#define RATINMAZE_H
#include <iostream>


class ratinmaze
{
public:
    ratinmaze();
    int [5][5] solution; //error
    virtual ~ratinmaze();
    ratinmaze(int N);
    void solveMaze(int [][5] maze, int N);
    bool findPath(int [][5] maze, int x, int y, int N, std::string direction);
    bool isSafeToGo(int [][5] maze, int x, int y, int N);
    void print(int [][5] solution, int N);
    void print(int [][5] solution, int N);
protected:

private:
    std::string direction;
    int N;
    int y;
    int x;
};

#endif // RATINMAZE_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ratinmaze.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int N = 5;
int[5][5] maze = {{ 1, 0, 1, 1,1 },
                 { 1, 1, 1, 0,1 },
                 { 0, 0,0, 1, 1 },
                 { 0, 0, 0, 1,0 },
                 { 0, 0,0, 1, 1 }};
ratinmaze r = new ratinmaze(N);
r.solveMaze(maze, N);
return 0;
}
```

I get the error in the first line :

> expected unqualifie-id before '[' token and in the following i get
>   "error : expected ',' or '...' before 'maze'

If u guys could help me I would be really appreciated!

---

**@update**

I figured out that I was not creating the right way my arrays but I have an error here on my main : `ratinmaze r = new ratinmaze(N);`

the error is :

> invalid conversion from 'ratinmaze*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Any idea ?

Comment: Re-read the part of your textbook where it tells you how to declare array variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in C++ are declared with the square brackets after the variable name, like so:

```
int solution[5][5];
```

Comment: yes i figured it out, i updated my question can u check it pls ?

Comment: @TimThom: you should not piggy-pack new questions over old ones. You figured out the first one? great! **Write an answer** here by yourself, so everyone knows you're done (or delete this question), and write a new question about the new problem. Otherwise you start dragging a "thread" that noone will be able to answer correctly because the question is always hanging..